# redirect www and non-www to https www .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Please don't say, its duplicate I have been through all threads but none of them worked for me.

I have installed SSL and want to redirect www and non-www to https://www

I have this code .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ven7\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ven7.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This is working fine, redirecting domain.com to https://www.ven7.com
But if I hit www.ven7.com, page is loading fine but its taking http, so I have changed script to..

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ven7\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ven7\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ven7.com/$1 [R,L]
```

With this code redirection is working but page is not loading, giving some error, too many re-directions.

How can i fix this? and want this redirection permanently.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.ven7.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

If you need to test the domain name, add first line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)ven7\.com$ [NC]
```

And use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)ven7\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.ven7.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Croises, Thanks for your reply, redirection is happening but page is showing error,  can you pls open www.ven7.com and see

Comment: @John https redirects to itself : too many redirects. Did you reload your server (assuming apache or similar)

Comment: Yes Croises, I am using those 5 lines only, btw its not wordpress, its static website contains 5 html pages.

Comment: I try with SERVER_PORT, that can be a problem with your SSL implementation